# Are ArrayLists mutable?

Tags: java, arraylist, immutability

I have a class containing the Arraylist `ArrayList<Move> moves`.
I call the getter of that Arraylist from another class and add a move: `panel.getMoves().add(move)`. But when I am iterating through the Arraylist afterwards, some really weird errors occur, hinting to the moves not being added correctly.

Do I have to call `panel.setMoves(panel.getMoves().add(move))`? If so, why, I always thought Lists were mutable?

Comment: For sure they are mutable. How about sharing these weird errors with us so we can help you further?

Comment: "some really weird errors occur", post them

Comment: well no actual _errors_ occur, but unexpected values etc. do, which is what I meant by "weird errors"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how `getMoves()` is implemented.

It could return a copy of the internal `ArrayList` (you have to call `setMoves(ArrayList)` in order to update it), or publish a direct reference to it (you don't need the setter). The latter indicates bad encapsulation, though.

Any instance of the class `ArrayList` is mutable. It's basically a wrapper over a dynamically-sized array. Its elements can be modified.